# How do i subtract 2 columns in a .csv file in R?

Tags: r, sum, subtraction

How to subtract 2 colmun in a .csv file uploaded in R?

I have named the new column using reading <- $started_time-  $ended_time

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not post any example data I post an example based on the `iris` built-in dataset: You can simply use `-` to subtract vector of the same length (if the length is not the same the shorter vector will be recycled).
You can select the column from your dataset with the `$` operator or with `[]` operator

```
data(iris)
#assigning the result to a new column 
iris$subtraction <- iris$Sepal.Length-iris$Sepal.Width
iris$subtraction <- iris[,1]-iris[,2]

#assigning the result to a new variable
subtraction <- iris[,1]-iris[,2]
subtraction <- iris$Sepal.Length-iris$Sepal.Width
```

**EDIT**

a `mincrobenchmark` of 3 equivalent solutions:

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#prepare simulation ------------------------------------------------------------

#number of rows to be tested
nr <- seq(100000,10000000,100000)

#initialize an list to store results
time <- as.list(rep(NA,100))

#benchmark
for (i in 1:length(nr)) {
  set.seed(5)
  #create data
  df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(nr[i]),y=rnorm(nr[i]))
  dt <- data.table(x=rnorm(nr[i]),y=rnorm(nr[i]))
  
  #benchmark
  x <- print(microbenchmark(
    base=df$new.col <- df$x-df$y,
    DT=dt <- dt[,new.col:=x-y],
    dplyr=df %>% mutate(new.col=x-y),
    times = 10
  ))
  #store results
  time[[i]] <- x[,c(1,4)]
}

#discard the first 4 elements because they run in microsenconds 
bench <- do.call(rbind,time[5:100])
#add the number of rows as column 
bench$nrow <- rep(nr[5:100],each=3)
ggplot(bench,aes(x=nrow,y=mean,group=expr,col=expr))+
  geom_smooth(se=F)+
  theme_minimal()+
  xlab("# rows")+
  ylab("time (milliseconds)")
```

[image]

As you can see, for this simple task both the `base` and `data.table` solutions are equivalent, while the `mutate` solution is a bit slower. However, the entire simulation runs in a minute and the single operations in few milliseconds.
my PC has 16Gb RAM and 12 cores.

**EDIT**

After the OP asked for a `Date` case, here a small example with date as `POSIXct` class:

```
day <- Sys.Date()
hm <- merge(0:23, seq(0, 45, by = 15))
datetime <- merge(last7days, chron(time = paste(hm$x, ':', hm$y, ':', 0)))
colnames(datetime) <- c('date', 'time')

# create datetime
dt <- as.POSIXct(paste(datetime$date, datetime$time))

df <- data.frame(x=sample(dt,200000,replace = T),y=sample(dt,200000,replace = T))
microbenchmark(df$x-df$y)
```

the operation runs in a few milliseconds, as expected:

```
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 df$x - df$y 1.459801 1.544301 2.755227 1.624501 1.845401 62.7416   100
```

Comment: Yes this i know in case of small data set but I have .csv file with about 200000 rows to subtract

Comment: It should not be a problem. With just 200,000 rows, depends on the computer, it should run in a few seconds or at least minutes. However, you can try the `data.table` package, that is designed to handle large dataset and it works in parallel by default. As soon as possible I will post an example benchmark for different solutions

Comment: ok How do  i upload .csv file on stackerflow to upload the case so as to explain better ,

Comment: You can copy and paste the output of `dput(head(your.data,50))` to give a taste of your csv, or upload the csv in a google drive and share the link. However, you should edit your question to better explain your need, and post your effort so far with a reproducible example.

Comment: started_at ended_at ride_length
4/26/2020 17:45 4/26/2020 18:12 0.018622685
4/17/2020 17:08 4/17/2020 17:17 0.005659722
4/18/2020 15:49 4/18/2020 16:24 0.024664352
4/19/2020 13:39 4/19/2020 14:01 0.015069444
This is short preview of my data the ride leghth is calculated by subtracting started_at- ended_at currently i did it in excel but if I want to do it using R wat commonad do a use to create a new colmun ride_length in R whose output would be ended_at-started_at (subtract),

Comment: you should have said right away that this is an operation between dates. However, It does not change anything: you can always do `df$ended_at - df$started_at`. The output will depend on the class of the date. I add an example with dates